# R, Calculating list of groups an object is belonging to

Tags: r

I have a data frame as follows. Practically each row corresponding to a group of items. 1st column corresponding to group name. Columns with heading `V1 ... V9` corresponding to object IDs of group members. Last two columns `(X and Y)` represent some scores corresponding to each group. `Object ID`s are `0 ... 332`.

```
 df2 = read.table(text='Cluster V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 X Y
   C1 82 135 178 197 205 261 271 308 311 10 110
   C2  4  30  72 105 145 203 330  NA  NA 12 191
   C3 22  66 135 195 214 282 291  NA  NA 11 184
   C4 14  16  25  28 309 327 328  NA  NA  8 131
   C5 41 116 125 156 234 311 313  NA  NA  7 138
   C6  6  80 125 137 139 286 311  NA  NA  6 198       
   C7 17  39  71  88 114 241 309  NA  NA  5 180
   C8 64 150 174 183 225 244  NA  NA  NA  4 200
   C9 24 101 118 268 305 314  NA  NA  NA  3 138
  C10 31 125 128 270 281 321  NA  NA  NA  2 101
             ', stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE)




> df
         C V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9  X   Y
 1       C1 82 135 178 197 205 261 271 308 311 10 110
 2       C2  4  30  72 105 145 203 330  NA  NA 12 191
 3       C3 22  66 135 195 214 282 291  NA  NA 11 184
 4       C4 14  16  25  28 309 327 328  NA  NA  8 131
 5       C5 41 116 125 156 234 311 313  NA  NA  7 138
 6       C6  6  80 125 137 139 286 311  NA  NA  6 198
 7       C7 17  39  71  88 114 241 309  NA  NA  5 180
 8       C8 64 150 174 183 225 244  NA  NA  NA  4 200
 9       C9 24 101 118 268 305 314  NA  NA  NA  3 138
 10     C10 31 125 128 270 281 321  NA  NA  NA  2 101
```

For each `object ID` I want to get the list of groups they belonging to. If an object is not belonging to any group it can result with a `NA`.

Note : number of members in groups can be different.

Appreciate a suggestion on an efficient method using `R` as I would have relatively high rows and columns in my `dataframe`.

I managed to get the output as below with the answer by `@RyanMorton`. 
`Table A`

```
           memberID Group
   1         4      C2
   2         6      C6
   3        14      C4
   4        16      C4
   5        17      C7
   6        22      C3
   7        24      C9
   8        25      C4
   9        28      C4
   10       30      C2
   11       31     C10
   12       39      C7
```

What I missing here is, members who are not grouped into any group need to be filled with a separate group ID e.g (C1000). In this case, I know member IDs are from 0 to 332. How do I fill those missing information?

Simply if I take memberIds from 0 to 10 final results would be as follows;
`Table B`

```
     memberID Group

   1    0   C1000
   2    1   C1000
   3    2   C1000
   4    3   C1000
   5    4   C2
   6    5   C1000
   7    6   C6
   8    7   C1000
   9    8   C1000
   10   9   C1000
   11   10  C1000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the table long form and then group by memberID using tidyr and dplyr:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- df2 %>% 
 gather("groupID","memberID", 2:(ncol(df2)-2)) 
 df <- df[,-(2:4)]
 df <- df[order(df$memberID),]
```

Edit: should produce desired table now.

Comment: Making the table from wide to long format solved my problem to some extent. Since I want to get the names of groups for each member do not want to use `summarise`. Now I want to fill up my results with the member IDs who are not belonging to any of the group.

Comment: How do you want those group names to appear?

Comment: I managed to get it with two columns "member ID" "groupID". If a member belongs several groups I would have multiple rows for that user. This is fine for me at this moment. I will update the question with what I would like to get as my result.

Comment: `@RyanMorton` I have updated the question with what I need to get as results

Comment: Ok, I think my edited answer still gets that result, assuming C100 is a cluster not provided in the original data.

Comment: `@RyanMorton` In the input data I do not get C1000, as I am getting the input as a result of another program. What I finally want to do is, once we get the output as `Table A` (refer updated question) (with the help of your answer), I need to reformat it as `Table B` (sample of the expected output) adding missing member IDs from (0 to 332), I know how many members should be there in the output. Is there way that I can add that missing lines in to the `Table A` to become `Table B`

Comment: I managed to get the final output the way I wanted by creating a seperate dataframe and merging it with the previous output.  `df5 <- data.frame(c(0:332))` `names(df5) <- c("memberID")' `df5 <- merge.data.frame(df,df5,all=TRUE)` `df5[is.na(df5)] <- as.character("C1000")`

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
df <- df2 %>%
  gather("groupID","memberID", 2:ncol(df2)) %>%
  group_by(memberID) %>%
  unnest(Cluster) %>% 
  mutate(new = 1) %>% 
  spread(Cluster, new, fill = 0)
```

this results in:

```
> head(df3)
Source: local data frame [6 x 12]
Groups: memberID [6]

  groupID memberID    C1   C10    C2    C3    C4    C5    C6    C7    C8    C9
    <chr>    <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1      V1        4     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
2      V1        6     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
3      V1       14     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
4      V1       17     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
5      V1       22     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
6      V1       24     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider base R with `reshape` and `lapply`:

```
# RESHAPE WIDE TO LONG
rdf <- reshape(df2, idvar=c("Cluster", "X", "Y"), varying=colnames(df2)[2:10],
               v.names = "V", direction="long")
rownames(rdf) <- seq(nrow(rdf))

# NAMED LIST OF GRPS BY EACH OBJECT ID
grplist <- setNames(lapply(unique(sort(rdf$V)), function(x) {
                    lst <- rdf[rdf$V==x, c("Cluster")]
                    lst <- lst[!is.na(lst)]
          }), unique(sort(rdf$V)))

grplist
# $`4`
# [1] "C2"

# $`6`
# [1] "C6"

# $`14`
# [1] "C4"

# $`16`
# [1] "C4"

# $`17`
# [1] "C7"

# $`22`
# [1] "C3"
```

IDs with Multiple Groups:

```
# $`125`
# [1] "C10" "C5"  "C6" 
# $`309`
# [1] "C4" "C7"
# $`311`
# [1] "C5" "C6" "C1"
```